# How can Python Poetry be forced to use a certain setuptools version?

Tags: python, setuptools, python-packaging, python-poetry

I would like to use the Python library `pyhash` in my project. The dependencies are managed by Poetry. If I add `pyhash` as a dependency, I get a build error: `error in pyhash setup command: use_2to3 is invalid`.

This is a well-known bug due to `setuptools > 58.0.0` not supporting `use_2to3` anymore. In a non-Poetry setup, the fix is easy. Just downgrade setuptools to <= 58.0.0: `pip3 install setuptools==58.0.0`.

However, in a Poetry project, I could not make this work. I added `setuptools=58.0.0` as a dependency, but when I install my project I still get the `use_2to3` error. I assume that poetry still uses a `setuptools>58.0.0`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Not easily fixable, really. One way to go would be to switch to Python 3.7 because PyPI has wheels of pyhash for Python 3.7. Other way to go would be to clone pyhash and fix it yourself (and maybe upload to PyPI, possibly under a different name, or on your own package index server).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround for my problem. In the case of [pyhash](https://github.com/flier/pyfasthash), the dependency on `use_2to3` [has already been removed](https://github.com/flier/pyfasthash/commit/20bd7cd219b7d37996453699423f0883c16e6956) in the `master` branch. This fix has unfortunately not been released yet. However, it is possible for pip and also for poetry to install directly from a github repository. Any ref can be specified, so branches, tags and also individual commits.

The workaround with poetry means you have to add the pyhash dependency with the git repository as source:

```
poetry add git+https://github.com/flier/pyfasthash.git#20a53f9bb7bf15f98e3e549f523b49e1e0f62e15
```

One can also specify `master`, but this is not advisable, as any branch is a moving target and will lead to non-reproducable releases.